# How do I set an environment variable in a Unity session?

Tags: unity, environment-variables

As a work-around to an issue with ibus, I'm trying to unset the variable $IBUS_ENABLE_SYNC_MODE. I have tried placing "unset IBUS_ENABLE_SYNC_MODE" in various places including:

- .profile
- .bashrc
- /etc/environment
- as a startup application

However, none of this is reflected in applications launched in Unity; for example, when I launch a terminal from Unity the result is:

```
~$ echo $IBUS_ENABLE_SYNC_MODE
1
```

Where should I set this variable so that Unity sources it properly?

**Edit:** The reason why my attempts are not working was because IBUS_ENABLE_SYNC_MODE is set internally by Unity code on start-up. So, short of modifying and recompiling Unity by hand, this does not have a solution.

Answer (score 8):

The easy way to set personal environment variables for Unity (or any other X session) is to add them to the file `$HOME/.xsessionrc`.  These variables are seen by everything launched in the session, via menus, GUIs, terminal windows, etc.  For example, put this text in `$HOME/.xsessionrc`:

```
# File sourced by /etc/X11/Xsession, for setting environment variables, etc.
export FOOVAR=testing
```

Log out and back in, then from a shell window:

```
my-pc> echo $FOOVAR
testing
```

Tested under 12.04, using Unity.  But this feature is implemented by the `/etc/X11/Xsession` script used by many types of desktop session, so it should work with any session type.  See the `Xsession` man page.

Answer (score 1):

Create a file in `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/` for it, e.g. `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/98local` (it has to be executed before `99x11-common_start`).

If this doesn't work try to find out where the variable gets set. Something like

```
sudo grep -r IBUS_ENABLE_SYNC_MODE /etc/
```

may help here to find the file.

Comment: Unfortunately, no luck. :\

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what you are trying to do with this but usually every variable that needs to be "global" is set or unset in `/etc/bash.bashrc` so you have to edit this file.

Comment: I need the change to be not only visible in bash shells but also in every application launched, including Firefox, LibreOffice etc. This work around basically fixes an issue where a space character is committed before a Korean glyph, causing unfortunate spacing issues like 가나_다 instead of 가나다.

Comment: in my experience bash.bashrc does this job correctly, basically it's a script invoked at every boot time by the OS so it's probably what are you looking for; if i set something in this file, after the reboot is available to the entire system.

Comment: Not everybody uses bash.