# Environment variable blank inside application

Tags: gui, environment-variables

I have an environment variable that I've set in `~/.profile` with the following line:

> export APPDIR=/path/to/dir

When I log in and load up a terminal, I can verify that the variable is set:

> $ printenv APPDIR
>
> /path/to/dir

I'm trying to access this variable from within a Qt application:

> QString appdir = getenv("APPDIR");
>
> QTWARNING("dir: |" + appdir + "|");

The warning window that pops up shows me:

> dir: ||

What is going on here? Am I misunderstanding about how environment variables work in Ubuntu?

This is with a C++/Qt App on Ubuntu 11.10 x86.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you launch the program from a terminal, the environment variable will be set; by default Linux desktop environments do not run `~/.profile` while setting up the GUI, so settings from it are only available in terminals.  See [How do I set an environment variable in a Unity session?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82120/how-do-i-set-an-environment-variable-in-a-unity-session) for setting environment variables for the GUI environment (this is not specific to Unity, but works for any X11 session).

Comment: Neither of the two answers given worked for me.

Comment: How are you starting the program? And right, Ubuntu changed its display manager and doesn't use that session config any more :/ unfortunately it looks like the rules are different for different Ubuntu releases which is not helpful. (Some read `.profile`, some `.gnomerc`, some want `.pam_environment`, some use that session file, some require editing files under `/usr/share/xsessions`, etc. Consistency is not for Ubuntu users, apparently.)

Comment: I was starting the program with `sudo ./appbinary`. After your comment I realized that it was loading different environment variables for sudo. I stopped using sudo (turned out the app didn't need it) and that fixed the problem. Thanks :]