# How to change AVD Data Directory on Linux?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am working in React Native using Android Studio. 
When I run Android Virtual Device in the emulator, I met this error :

> Emulator: emulator: ERROR: Not enough space to create userdata partition.

The default location of AVD data directory on Linux is ~/.android/avd/name.avd/ . The detail is [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline.html#data-filedir).
I have no idea how to run these :

> Use the -datadir option to specify a different AVD data directory.

Then I found [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/variables.html#android_emulator_home) :

> By default, the emulator stores configuration files under $HOME/.android/ and AVD data under $HOME/.android/avd/. You can override the defaults by setting the following environment variables. The emulator -avd  command searches the avd directory in the order of the values in $ANDROID_AVD_HOME, $ANDROID_SDK_HOME/.android/avd/, and $HOME/.android/avd/.

I tried several scripts below to my .bashrc file, which I want to change default location of AVD data directory :

```
export HOME=~/otherLocation
export ANDROID_HOME=~/otherLocation
export ANDROID_AVD_HOME=~/otherLocation
export ANDROID_SDK_HOME=~/otherLocation
```

But none of above scripts work for me.
Please help, any reply would be highly appreciate.. Thanks.

Comment: As error message says: there is not enough space. Your export commands is correct if they point to another partition where are enougnt space. You should run program in same terminal window where you put export commands.

Comment: @LeonidMew ..  I met error when i want to create Android Virtual Device, which it run through AVD Manager (Android Studio) GUI. not run through terminal.

Comment: To have export var effect you can run gui app from terminal, or look at(but it might not help) https://askubuntu.com/questions/82120/how-do-i-set-an-environment-variable-in-a-unity-session

Comment: update the absolute paths in .ini files which are available in that same folder
Ref: https://dev.to/oscherler/move-android-studio-virtual-devices-on-a-mac-5ej5